# How can I set the user's ip as column default?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

When a user is registered, I want to record their ip address.  How do I access the current ip and set it as the column default?

```
regi_ip = db.Column(db.String(24), default='???')
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you trying to create the table? Store the value? Fetch the value?

Comment: Each new recording must keep user ip addres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`request.remote_addr`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.remote_addr) to get the remote ip making the current request.  You cannot set that as the column default because the model definitions happen outside a request, and it wouldn't make sense to set the default here anyway.  When creating a new user, just say `my_new_user.regi_ip = request.remote_addr`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have such a [computed default value](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions), however ill-advised it would be:

```
def remote_addr():
    return request.remote_addr

...
    regi_ip = db.Column(db.String(24), default=remote_addr)
```

However, you probably want to make sure that the `remote_addr` does something sensible even if no request is available (maybe `try/except` with default value).